# How can i add two Manageable Banner section for Advertisement in front-end

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i add two  Manageable Banner section for Advertisement in below the slider and above the new products

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on home page

Go to admin navigate to "Cms->Pages" go to home page.

add below code between slider and new product

```
<div class="advertise_container">
  <div class="left-advertise"></div>
  <div class="right-advertise"></div>
</div>
```

style it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please create 2 static blocks with identifier leftads and rightads
   [image]
2. Includes it to the CMS pages you want

For left ads

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="leftads"}}
```

For right ads

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="rightads"}}
```

Comment: I created two static blocks, but in my CMS page content only this code <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>, So please give me Layout Update XML code